# Memoization helper

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, memoization

Please review:

```
/// Fetch a value from the `map` or create a new one from the `fun` (memoization).
/// Example: \code
///   flat_map<string, Frople> fcache;
///   Frople& frople = getOrElseUpdate (fcache, id, [&]() {return Frople (id);});
/// \endcode
template<typename M, typename K, typename F>
inline auto& getOrElseUpdate (M& map, const K& key, F fun) {
  auto it = map.find (key);
  if (it != map.end()) return it->second;
  return map.emplace (std::make_pair (key, fun())) .first->second;
}
```

Named after the [Scala method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map@getOrElseUpdate%28key:A,op:=%3EB%29:B).

The function is used to simplify the common map operations of checking whether there is a value in a map and generating the value if it isn't in the map, allowing one to use a simple to read one-liner instead of repeating these common but hard-to-read operations in the code.

---

P.S. Incorporating bits of advise from @vnp and @Loki reviews:

```
template<typename C, typename F>
inline auto getOrElseUpdate (C& map, typename C::key_type const& key, F funct) ->decltype (map[key]) {
  auto it = map.find (key);
  if (it != map.end()) return it->second;
  return map.emplace (key, funct()) .first->second;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/35180/15094

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your question is missing a lot of details to be clear. Could you add information about how is it used, what it's supposed to be used for and have a bigger picture.

Comment: @Marc-Andre: Thanks. Added the explanation. If that much isn't obvious from the documentation, though, then perhaps the documentation should be improved. Have any pointers?

Comment: It's not much on the method, but more for your question. It's hard to make a review on such a small piece of code without a proper context. Is is part of a class, are there other methods, is it use often, etc. The more information you give, the better your question will be.

Comment: It's not a part of a class, it's a general purpose method, like std::min. And one can say a lot about a simple method, if one wants to, cf. http://componentsprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/writing-min-function-part-1-the-rise-of-concepts/ If there is nothing to say, then one can say that the review is passed, the method looks okay. This is the purpose of the code review, after all, to see if the code is okay.

Comment: @ArtemGr: When tagging something C++11 it is also worth adding the tag C++ it helps things organize better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well overall impression is the code is very condensed. Some white space may help.

I am going to have to disagree with @vnp about the type names.
Its pretty common to use short template type names. Common conventions `T` generic type `C` container `K` key, `F` functor. If you have a lot then fine you may give more description but the type should be generic. I don't want to impose my thoughts on the user of the type (let the compiler impose its rules on the user). I would not want to limit the use of this to maps if it can generically be applied to other container types. As long as the parameter and variable names are descriptive then the type names don't need to be.

The `Key` type is unnecessary. This information can be extracted from the container.

Don't assume the internal value is `std::pair` use the container to tell you its internal value type `C::value_type` (yes its a `std::pair` for `std::map` but don't lock yourself to this type if you don't need to). But since you are using `emplace()` you should not be passing the internal object (that's relay for `insert()`). You can just pass the parameters used to construct the internal type.

Don't like the emplace and return of a part of the result in a single line.

```
template<typename C, typename F>
inline auto getOrElseUpdate(C& associativeCont, typename C::key_type const& key, F funct) -> decltype (associativeCont[key])
{
    auto it = associativeCont.find(key);

    if (it != associativeCont.end())
    {   return it->second;
    }

    // pair<iterator, bool>
    //    iterator points at inserted value
    //    bool indicates success. Since
    //    we already checked for an existing value it will
    //    always succeed so no need to re-check.
    auto inserted = associativeCont.emplace(key, function());

    // Return the value that was inserted.
    return inserted.first->second;
}
```

Comment: Short template names are OK. Template types reduced to _typename_ are not. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Template parameters are not informative. Better do something like

```
#define Maptype typename
#define Keytype typename
#define Function typename

template <Maptype M, Keytype K, Function F>
```

I was seriously confused with `fun`. Better call it `function`.

---

The code failed to compile on my system (GCC 4.7.3). First, `auto` function was missing a trailing return type; fixed by adding

```
-> decltype(map[key])
```

and changing `auto&` to just `auto`. I don't know C++11 well enough to blame your compiler (which compiles your code) or mine (which doesn't).

Then it happened so that GCC 4.7.3 does not have `emplace`. Known GCC problem.

Comment: Thanks. I compile with `gcc 4.8.3` and `--std=c++1y`, sorry for the confusion.